# How to get 4th number in a line in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to calculate space count percentage from hadoop. I'm trying to develop a script related to that. - I'm using command 'hadoop fs -count -q -h /db/xxxxx'

- this is the output i get
  100 T         100.0 T           260 T          **16.3** T       51.5 K      672.6 K             81.2 T /db/XXXXX
- i need to get the 16.3 number to calculate the usage percentage.
  Anyone did it using similar method? any help is appreciated.!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get the best, fastest responses.

Similarly, make sure you're asking the right, *real* question.
This could easily be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). State your end goal, and show what you are currently trying.

Finally, c.f. http://idownvotedbecau.se/ - specifically, [No Attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

That said, maybe try something like this?

```
hadoop fs -count -q -h /db/xxxxx | awk -F'[^0-9.]+' '{print $4}'
```

That tells `awk` to pattern-split the line on one or morte nondigit(or dot) characters.